# xml feed vs xml document parsing -- the difference?

Tags: xml, parsing, feed

When parsing XML like below, does book.xml need to be a static file of xml or can I use a dynamic feed url of RSS? Does a feed URL need to end in XML or can it simply be the URL (like: http://feeds.voices.washingtonpost.com/wp/reliable-source/index)?

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else // IE 5/6
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET","books.xml",false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
```

Comment: why don't you try it and see if it works?

Comment: I did try it, didn't work. Suppose I'm trying to isolate the problem. Thanks anyway, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL does not have to end in ".xml".  Any URL will do.